# strange 0xF0B8 constant in CRC verification

Tags: crc, ccitt

I'm studying a working program that between others verifies the validity of an incoming message. The CRC used is  CCITT 16, the initial value of the CRC is set to 0xFFFF, and the message is sent in bytes that are received LSb first and the bytes the MSB first. The message forms a long bitstream up to 1024 bits long, including the 16 CRC bits at the end.

I fully understand the calculation of the CRC value. What puzzles me, and I can find no reference justifying it, is the validity check performed after all message has been received. Namely, the CRC value is checked against 0xF0B8 instead of 0x0000. Am I missing something?

```
// crcValue is the 16 bit CRC variable under construction
// dataBit is a byte containing one bit of the data bitstream at LSb

...

// CRC calculation bit by bit

if(dataBit ^ (crcValue & 0x0001)) crcValue = (crcValue >> 1) ^ 0x8408;
else                              crcValue >>=1;
          
//After running over all the bitstream the crcValue is checked 

if(crcValue != 0xF0B8) ... // reject data  
else ...  // accept data
```

The program works. As said I cannot understand where the 0xF0B8 value comes from.

Thank You in advance

Comment: This magic value is directly from RFC1549, except there it has been given a proper name: `PPPGOODFCS16`. It is due to FCS design: *The FCS was originally designed with hardware implementations in mind.  A serial bit stream is transmitted on the wire, the FCS is calculated over the serial data as it goes out, and the complement of the resulting FCS is appended to the serial stream, followed by the Flag Sequence. [...] Therefore, the FCS was designed so that a particular pattern results when the FCS operation passes over the complemented FCS.  A good frame is indicated by this "good FCS" value.*

Comment: I've come across the "magic number" but can't find any theory (math) to derive it. It seems I have to believe and just take it for granted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You left out the fact that are also inverting the CRC before appending to the message. Checking against `0x0000` would work if there were no final invert or other final exclusive-or. `0xf08b` is that CRC (initializing with `0xffff`, but not inverting the result) of two zero bytes, which is your appended CRC in the case of an empty message.

Comment: @rcgldr Correct. Thanks.